# SQL Server 2017 Failover Cluster on RHEL Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, clustering, sql-server-2017

I am trying to create Failover Cluster on SQL Server 2017 on RHEL 7.3 Linux, following this document from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-shared-disk-cluster-configure?view=sql-server-2017

I have installed SQL Server 2017 on both nodes (local storage) as per the document. But after step 3, there is note which says:

> At set up time, a Server Master Key is generated for the SQL Server
>   instance and placed at var/opt/mssql/secrets/machine-key. On Linux,
>   SQL Server always runs as a local account called mssql. Because it’s a
>   local account, its identity isn’t shared across nodes. Therefore, you
>   need to copy the encryption key from primary node to each secondary
>   node so each local mssql account can access it to decrypt the Server
>   Master Key.

Can anyone please help as to what exactly what to do here? Do I have to replace the server master key of the secondary node, by copying it from primary node. Or just have to copy and paste it there?

[image]